# Maven Custom Plugin - check for artifact with specific version in local repository for use outside project classpath

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to write a custom maven plugin for my org to download specific versions of tomcat (7, 8, or 9 depending on what they select) and install it to a conventional directory with application specific configs pulled from a different data source. The specific part I want help on is the fetching of tomcat. I COULD just redownload tomcat from the their website any time you run the script into a temp directory somewhere, but it really feels like I should be using mavens dependency infrastructure somehow to pull org.apache.tomcat:tomcat and unzip that.

Is there some way to write a maven plugin to resolve a specific version of a dependency to my local repository and NOT add it to the classpath of my project, such that I can just extract the zip artifact elsewhere?

Comment: I would actually copy it to the local repository to some custom path. And before redownloading, I would just check if it already there.